# monitoring a text site (json) using python

Tags: python, json, list

IM working on a program to grab variant ID from this website 
https://www.deadstock.ca/collections/new-arrivals/products/nike-air-max-1-cool-grey.json

Im using the code

```
import json
import requests
import time



endpoint = "https://www.deadstock.ca/collections/new-arrivals/products/nike-air-max-1-cool-grey.json"
req = requests.get(endpoint)
reqJson = json.loads(req.text)

for id in reqJson['product']:
    name = (id['title'])
    print (name)
```

I dont know what to do here in order to grab the Name of the items. If you visit the link you will see that the name is under 'title'. If you could help me with this that would be awesome.

I get the error message "TypeError: string indices must be integers" so im not too sure what to do.

Comment: please add the `send` code to the post

Comment: Ill just post it all. *note* links are removed though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your biggest problem right now is that you are adding items to the list before you're checking if they're in it, so everything is coming back as in the list.

Looking at your code right now, I think what you want to do is combine things into a single for loop.

Also as a heads up you shouldn't use a variable name like `list` as it is shadowing the built-in Python function `list()`.

```
list = []  # You really should change this to something else

def check_endpoint():
    endpoint = ""
    req = requests.get(endpoint)
    reqJson = json.loads(req.text)
    for id in reqJson['threads']:  # For each id in threads list
        PID = id['product']['globalPid']  # Get current PID
        if PID in list:
            print('checking for new products')
        else:
            title = (id['product']['title'])    
            Image = (id['product']['imageUrl'])
            ReleaseType = (id['product']['selectionEngine'])
            Time = (id['product']['effectiveInStockStartSellDate'])
            send(title, PID, Image, ReleaseType, Time)
            print ('added to database'.format(PID))
            list.append(PID)  # Add PID to the list
    return

def main():
    while(True):
        check_endpoint()
        time.sleep(20)
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: wow thank you very much! It works, now just gotta have it running untill the PID changes on the site.

Comment: If things are working, could you mark this as the accepted answer please? Glad I could help out!

Comment: Any updates that I can help with or is everything working now?

Comment: you know what, i actually forgot about this post. I started to work on another project today and ran into an error. Ill edit the post with the new project. Its actually of the same type too! @ejohnso49

Comment: Since you've got a new separate issue, I think it's best to open a new question. I'll go ahead and revert your question back to the previous state in case someone has a similar problem. Then you can post your new stuff into a new question. Thanks!